# Vector subscript out of range - C++

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, range

I am using visual studio 2013. I'm trying to get a subvector from a vector:

```
std::vector <Ponto> pontosDeControle;
std::vector<Ponto> subPontosDeControle;
```

the vector pontosDeControle is filled with some objects, then I get the subvector from position i to pontosDeControle.size()-1:

```
   subPontosDeControle = std::vector<Ponto>(&pontosDeControle[i], &pontosDeControle[pontosDeControle.size()]);
```

where i is less then pontosDeControle.size()-3.

This code is returning a debug assertion failed: Vector subscript out of range. However, on release mode works fine.

I'm not seeing the problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the debug mode the compiler checks that used index in this expression

```
pontosDeControle[pontosDeControle.size()]
```

is out of range.

You could write instead

```
subPontosDeControle.assign( std::next( pontosDeControle.begin(), i ),
                            pontosDeControle.end() );
```

It would be more clear and correct.

Answer (score 1):

For a vector `v` with size `v.size()` you can only access indices `0`...`v.size() - 1` (of course, if `v.siz() == 0` there is no accessible index). If you want to get a pointer to the element past the last one (you can get this address legally), you'd use something like this:

```
v.data() + v.size()
```

For the operations you want to use you don't need to use addresses of elements: you can use iterators instead:

```
subPontosDeControle.assign(pontosDeControl.begin() + i, pontosDeControl.end());
```